# Ping problems with two interfaces, same subnet, direct connections to two separate hosts

Tags: networking, ping, subnet, route, arp

I have a configuration of a client machine (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS) that directly connects to two server machines. The server machines--while on the same subnet--cannot route to each other. Packets must not route between the client's `eth1` and `eth2`, either (i.e., client is not a router) and since there's an act of discovery involved, the routing table cannot be pre-programmed with the serverX IPs.

Below is a crude diagram. `eth0` is left out of this picture as it cannot route to the subnet `172.16.37.0/24`. There are no firewalls (both `iptables` and `ufw` are clean as a whistle).

```
     client                         server01
+-------------------+          +-------------------+
| 172.16.37.53 eth1-|----------|-eth1 172.16.37.11 |
|                   |          +-------------------+
|                   |               server02
|                   |          +-------------------+
| 172.16.37.54 eth2-|----------|-eth1 172.16.37.12 |
+------------------ +          +-------------------+
```

The problem that I'm encountering is that `ping -I eth2 172.16.37.12` does not work from the client machine. In short, what I observe via `tcpdump` is:

- `client:eth2` issues ping-request
- `server02:eth1` receives ping-request
- `server02:eth1` issues an ARP who-has for `172.16.37.54`
- `client:eth2` receives the ARP who-has
- ARP never responds (and the arp cache isn't updated)

If I send gratuitous ARPs with `arping -A -I eth2 172.16.37.54` from the client, then the observation is thus:

- `client:eth2` issues ping-request
- `server02:eth1` receives ping-request
- `server02:eth1` issues ping-reply to client
- `client:eth2` receives ping-reply
- ping application never receives packet

When I `strace`d my ping session, it keeps retrying `recvmsg`; nothing shows up on the socket.

Here's the routing table for the aforementioned observations:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.187.2    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.16.37.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
172.16.37.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
172.16.187.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

If I add a host route into the routing table for `172.16.37.12 -> eth2`, then both ARP resolution and ping operation work as intended. However, I cannot pre-program the host routes since I need to discover the connected machines--all I have are the active interfaces and their subnets.

Packets are not received on `eth1` when testing `eth2` (I had pretty much all the interfaces being watched). It's also worth noting that this problem does not happen with `eth1`; it is able to `ping -I eth1` correctly without the host route entry (and due to route ordering, the `-I` option is excessive in this case, but generally I cannot rely on the order of the table).

Why isn't the application (in one case the ARP cache; the other `ping`) receiving the packets? How can I track down where the data is going? Everything *seems* to be operating correctly right up until the packet should be delivered to the application.

Comment: might be duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/415304/multiple-physical-interfaces-with-ips-on-the-same-subnet or http://serverfault.com/questions/336021/two-network-interfaces-and-two-ip-addresses-on-the-same-subnet-in-linux

Comment: imo, if you have two different static routes to the same network, you're looking for trouble. i'd think about other solutions.

Comment: @Marco Thanks for the links; the first is most closely related, the second isn't the same (he has a default gateway while my configuration has no default gateway).